# Centering horizontally breaks content on website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, vertical-alignment

I've tried lots of different methods of horizontally centering my website, but every single method either breaks the page or offsets it slightly. I'll try and elaborate as much as possible.

I have a website containing a Bootstrap grid of HTML5 videos. You can preview the site here: [www.watchthis.limited](http://www.watchthis.limited) I want the entire grid to be positioned horizontally to display an equal sized black bar above and below the content. I'm currently using a wrapper with a padding-top of 10%, but this isn't a good solution because the content isn't directly in the middle on all browsers.

I'm pretty sure the main problem is that there is no fixed height because I want the content to stretch to the browser size (so each image is 100% width, height:auto). When I tried to absolutely position the page the content just fixes to the top of the page. This is the code that I tried to apply to the wrapper before resorting to padding-top:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

I've also tried setting the content as a table and setting the child to vertical-align middle, but that still offsets the content in the middle for some reason. So, any ideas? How do you vertically align a grid of images which have no fixed height or width - is it even possible? Any help will be more than appreciated,

Thanks.

Note: I know that the page breaks when it's viewed on smaller devices, I'm currently in the process of changing the website for mobile devices.

Comment: let me know if this answer not solved your problem? but it should i personally went to your website worked on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this css**

```
.wrapper{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

parent div for `.wrapper` is currently `body`(or make on div) so add

```
    body{
    display: table;
    height:100%; //removed 800px;
    }
```

Comment: You sir, are a saint. I thought I had tried the table solution previously but obviously I had missed something. Thank you!